# Зажатие кнопки на Python

Tags: python, клавиатура

Я сделал кликер на пайтоне, но его активация зависит от того, зажал ли я вручную заданную кнопку.

Как можно сделать что бы я раз нажал, и оно работало до кнопки, отключающей ее?

Мой модуль:

```
import pyautogui as auto
import keyboard as key

Мой код: 

start_key = input("Клавиша запуска: ")
    stop_key = input("Клавиша остановки: ")
    while True:
        if key.is_pressed(start_key):
            (auto.click(clicks=1))
    
        if key.is_pressed(stop_key):
            eshe = input("Работа окончена. Введите OK: ")        
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

Идея заключается в использовании понятия **состояние**. Для хранения состояния заведём специальную переменную:

```
was_pressed = False # Пока ещё не было нажатия

while True:
    if not was_pressed :
        # Ждём нажатия клавиши запуска
    else :
        # Ждём нажатия клавиши останова
```

Но учтите, что в реальности так писать программу нельзя. Потому, что она бесконечными опросами клавиатуры сожрёт всё время процессора.